# Not able to drop external elements on calendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, draggable, fullcalendar-4

when I drag an external element on the calendar, I am not able to create an event on the calendar through it. eventReceive() callback is also not getting fired.

I have set the droppable option to true as well. Can someone please help? Have a look at the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="fc-event">Drag me !!</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.fc-event').each(() => {
        // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
        $(this).data('event', {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
            stick: true, // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
            duration: '02:00',
            create: true,
        });

        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0, //  original position after the drag
        });
    });
    const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
        themeSystem: 'standard',
        selectable: true,
        droppable: true,
        columnHeader: true,
        selectMirror: true,
        editable: true,
        plugins: [interactionPlugin, dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin],
        eventResourceEditable: true,

        select(selectionInfo) {
            showTaskCreationPopup(selectionInfo.start, selectionInfo.end);
        },

        eventReceive(element) {
            console.log('event received');
            createTask(element.event);
        },

        drop(info) {
            console.log('dropped');
            createTask(info.jsEvent);
        },

        eventDrop(info) {
            console.log('event dropped');
        },

        header: {
            left: 'prevYear prev today next nextYear',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
        },

        buttonText: {
        // eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
            prevYear: new moment().year() - 1,
            // eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
            nextYear: new moment().year() + 1,
        },
    });
    calendar.render();
```

Comment: It's not clear if you enabled jQueryUI as a third-party dragging library, as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/third-party-dragging ? This is a necessary step in fullCalendar v4. Otherwise, you can just use fullCalendar's built-in Draggable class, as perhttps://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging

Answer (score 0):

The way that I was able to achieve this was not through the eventReceive -neither eventDrop- event but using the 'drop' event. The signature is something like:

customDrop = ({ resource, date, draggedEl: { id } }) => {})

Answer (score 0):

```
var containerEl = document.getElementById('external-events-list');
var eventEls = Array.prototype.slice.call(
 containerEl.querySelectorAll('.fc-event')
 );
 eventEls.forEach(function(eventEl) {


if (eventEl.textContent == "Event1") {
  new Draggable(eventEl, {
    eventData: {
      id: 1,
      title: eventEl.innerText.trim(),
      color: 'Orange',
      textColor:'black'
    }
  });
} else if (eventEl.textContent == "Event2") {
  new Draggable(eventEl, {
    eventData: {
      id: 2,
      title: eventEl.innerText.trim(),
      color: '#ccccff',
      textColor:'black'
    }
  });

   }}); // end eventEls.forEach
```